# laravel database queue worker not picking jobs

Tags: laravel, queue, supervisord

I am running 8 workers in supervisor, while started jobs processing it will start executing 8 jobs parallel but once any of job fails or completed it will not pic another job until all 8 workers gets free.
You can refer image as there are 8 workers it should run 8 jobs but only one is running.
[image]

Comment: it is not working even after limited tries?

Comment: It will pull another job only all workers are free. I think it should pick the job once any worker is free.